# creating a rss feed with php

Tags: php, rss

I have a list of tweets which I want to feed to twitter every hour or so.
WHat si the best way to go about makign an rss fee where I can insert text/tweets to be randomally posted every hour??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best PHP lib/class to generate RSS/Atom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182510/what-is-the-best-php-lib-class-to-generate-rss-atom) and a [couple of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rss+php) in addition to those that have been suggested to you when you entered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is excellent library out there for that [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/)

> SimplePie is a very fast and
>   easy-to-use class, written in PHP,
>   that puts the 'simple' back into
>   'really simple syndication'.  Flexible
>   enough to suit beginners and veterans
>   alike, SimplePie is focused on speed,
>   ease of use, compatibility and
>   standards compliance.

Comment: How do  I add random posts to the feed?

Comment: @jaksta: See this tutorial: http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-rss.html and simplepie docs http://simplepie.org/wiki/